# ShareLatex Word Count: Massive error

Tags: sharelatex, word-count

I am writing my report in shareLatex, an online latex environment, and when I click *Word Count* in the menu, it shows me the number of words, headers and math inlines.

However, it also shows me the following HUGE error, of which there is no record in the logs and also doesn't seem to pose any problems for compiling...

```
!!! Could not recognise package list, ignoring it instead. !!!
!!! Encountered } without corresponding {. !!!
!!! Encountered } without corresponding {. !!!
!!! Encountered } without corresponding {. !!!
!!! Reached end of file while waiting for }. !!!
!!! Reached end of file while waiting for }. !!!
!!! Reached end of file while waiting for }. !!!
!!! Encountered } without corresponding {. !!!
!!! Encountered \end without corresponding \begin !!!
!!! Encountered } without corresponding {. !!!
!!! Encountered \end without corresponding \begin !!!
!!! Reached end of file while waiting for \end. !!!
!!! Environment ended while waiting for nd{center}. !!!
!!! Reached end of file while waiting for }. !!!
!!! Reached end of file while waiting for \end. !!!
!!! Environment ended while waiting for nd{center}. !!!
!!! Reached end of file while waiting for }. !!!
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some code, preferably as minimal as possible, that is sufficient to produce the error. The first line is only a warning that you are including packages for which TeXcount does not have macro handling rules, which is generally not a big problem. The remaining errors all seem related to not being able to determine matching group starts and ends.

Comment: @Einar I would love to. But as I stated, there appears no error when I am compiling. I just looked through the raw logs, but I cannot find anything that looks like this. I have a project spanning 23 files,  well over 300 kB. If you want an MWE I'd love to give it. I doubt however, that it's going to fit in a post.

Comment: One method is to try running TeXcount on a trimmed down version of your document: eg start off with only one of the files included. Also, you can try running TeXcount in verbose mode, option `-v`, to help identify where the errors are reported, although I'm not sure the errors will occur exactly where the problem lies.

Comment: This should be marked duplicate. [Here's your answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286019/how-can-i-convince-texcount-that-my-use-of-newcolumntype-is-perfectly-valid-syn)